# Cloud Datastore backup and restoring API

Tags: database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, database-backups

We are able to store Cloud Datastore entities using backup.create endpoint provided by GAE.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scheduled_backups#Specifying_Backups_in_a_Cron_File

We want to implement a feature like give an option to users restore their backups. But seems there is no restore endpoint API in GAE.

I observed that we have to login in Cloud Datastore admin console and do the restore process by selecting the GCS file path.

Is there a way to do this like GCS dump load and restore the database using java platform?

Comment: Please suggest if anybody have the info about the query.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling on this, this is [available via the API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/admin/rest#rest-resource:-v1.projects). Details for [export](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/admin/rest/v1/projects/export) and [import](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/admin/rest/v1/projects/import), which are the equivalents to Create Backup and Restore Backup.

```
POST https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{projectId}:export
POST https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{projectId}:import
```